# Use ant to execute SQL that uses tables that reside in 2 different Oracle schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, ant

I have to automate the execution of an sql cript which uses tables that reside in two different Oracle schema. I was advised to use ant for this task. Is it really possible to do that with ant? Currently, we are using SQL developer for this task.

The SQL task looks like this: 
update schema1.table1 jb 
set jb.id=value 
where jb.another_id in (select wrd.proc_inst_id_ 
                                       from schema1.table2 wrd 
                                                            where wrd.long_ in (set of values));

where value is determined with select on tables in schema1
and **set of values is determined with select on tables from schema2**

The two schemas reside in the same Oracle instance.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the answer? I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you Lalit, granting rights solves the problem. Another way is creating Database link.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Please mark the answer as answered then, it would help others looking for a similar solution.

Comment: By the way, you don't need dblink between two schemas, you need it between two different databases. You have no where mentioned that they are different databases. All you said is that they are different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, we are using SQL developer for this task.

Irrespective of the tool you use, all you need is the **PRIVILEGE** to access/manipulate the **TABLES** in different **SCHEMAS**. Your question doesn't get into details whether you are just doing a **SELECT** or any **DML** on the table. So, I am not getting deeper into the details.

For example, just to do a select on a table, you need to grant the select privilege:

`GRANT SELECT ON table_name to user_name`

Similarly, to do any kind of **DML** on the tables in other schema, you need to grant the required privileges to the user..

If you have the privileges, you just need to access the tables as:

`SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME`